# Orthogonal Complement being a subspace of Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis

i) Let $Y$ is just a subspace of $H$. Is it true that $Y^\perp$ is also a subspace of $H$?

ii) Let $Y$ be a closed subspace of a Hilbert space $H$. Is it true that $Y^\perp$ is also a subspace of $H$?

Which one is true?

Comment: $Y^{\perp}$ is $\bigcap_{y\in Y}\{ x : \langle y,x\rangle = 0 \}$, which is  an intersection of subspaces.

Comment: do I need the condition of $Y$ being closed?

Comment: There is no condition on $Y$ in what I wrote at all. $Y$ can be a non-empty subset of $H$, and it is still true that $Y^{\perp}$ is a closed subspace because it is the intersection of kernels of continuous linear functionals, $\Phi_y(x)=\langle x,y\rangle$.